# How to property adjust table?

Tags: css

I have this simple code.

```
<div class="rating" >
<table>
<tr>
     <th> Award </th>
     <th> Winner </th>
     <th> Runner-up </th>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Starburst Award </td>
    <td> #winner </td>
    <td> #runner-up#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Rising Star Award </td>
    <td> #winner </td>
    <td> #runner-up#</td>

</tr>
 <tr>
    <td> Shooting Star Award  </td>
    <td> #winner </td>
    <td> #runner-up#</td>

</tr>   
 <tr>
    <td> Shining Star Award </td>
    <td> #winner......................... </td>
    <td> #runner-up#.....................................</td>

</tr>   
</table>
</div>
table.rating, th,tr,td
{
 width:100%;   
border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black; height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Using the css I want to make better. How can I have it that it looks more like a table and not be separated like that, and have the   be in the middle?
I have created a http://fiddle.jshell.net/9axbx/ , all I really want to do make the table look better.

Comment: your table is already looks 'ok' but what does mean Great for you? Than I will be able to post an answer. How do you wants the table looks like?

Comment: Why do you set table width to 100% and cell height to 50px? Why do no you have strings of periods in the cells? These are obvious things that make it look *worse*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sets it up more like a table:

```
<div class="rating" >
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th> Award </th>
 <th> Winner </th>
 <th> Runner-up </th>    
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> Starburst Award </td>
 <td> #winner </td>
 <td> #runner-up#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> Rising Star Award </td>
 <td> #winner </td>
 <td> #runner-up#</td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td> Shooting Star Award  </td>
 <td> #winner </td>
 <td> #runner-up#</td>

</tr>   
<tr>
 <td> Shining Star Award </td>
 <td> #winner</td>
 <td> #runner-up#</td>

</tr>   
</table>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  table.rating, th,tr,td
  {
    width: 30%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black; 
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but that should be a good start. You really should have the `<style></style>` tags inside the `<head></head>` of your html document, but the above still works, for demonstration purposes.

EDIT: Just a note on the changes I made--

I first removed the periods after the text in the last couple of cells. Not quite sure what you put them there for. Second, I added `text-align:center` to your CSS. If you don't want the text centered, you can change it to, say, `text-align:left` to align it to the left. Third, You do not need a border, and if you don't want one just remove the `border` options from the CSS. Finally, I changed the width of your cells to 30%, so they all should be the same width. This makes things much neater and cleaner. 100% makes a cell the full width of the table, which I assume you don't want. If you want a cell to take up more than one column you should use the `colspan` attribute.